# css javascript active function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, frontend

Trying to create a basic drop down menu that appears once size of screen reaches certain pixels.

HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="navigation">

                <a href="#" class="hamburger">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                  </a>

                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </div>


                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Have a Javascript code that goes like this:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link-wrapper')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

And my CSS code goes like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .hamburger{
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation{
        /* display: none; */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 30px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(185, 22, 22);
        border-top: 2px solid rgb(185, 22, 22);
        font-size: large;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .nav-link-wrapper{
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        /* padding-top: 10px; */
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav-link-wrapper.active{  /*NOT GETTING ACTIVE*/
        display: flex;
        
    }

}
```

No matter what I try, the nav-link-wrapper.active does not happen. The nav bar does appear if I change display from 'none' to 'flex' so I know what it should look like, but the 'active' function from javascript doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Comment: navbarLinks refers to a collection of elements, not one element. So navbarLinks.classList does not make sense. Try using navbarLinks[0].classList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should have been showing the first `nav-link-wrapper` on click. This would have been because you were only storing the FIRST element with class `nav-link-wrapper` in `const navbarLinks` due to `[0]`.

In order to fix this, I've changed from `getElementsByClassName`, which produces a `HTMLCollection` which is more difficult to iterate, to `querySelectorAll` which produces an Array of elements.

Then inside your javascript, `onclick` you need to loop over all the elements stored inside `navbarLinks` by using `forEach`.

*In order to produce a usable example, I've commented out the `@media` query and added a pseudo-element to show "TOGGLE"*

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0];
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link-wrapper');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.forEach((it) => {
        it.classList.toggle('active');
    });
});
```

```css
/* @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) { */
    .hamburger:after { content:'TOGGLE' } /* Remove Me - Just for demo purposes */
    .hamburger{
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation{
        /* display: none; */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 30px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(185, 22, 22);
        border-top: 2px solid rgb(185, 22, 22);
        font-size: large;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .nav-link-wrapper{
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        /* padding-top: 10px; */
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav-link-wrapper.active{  /*NOT GETTING ACTIVE*/
        display: flex;
        
    }
/* } */
```

```html
<div class="navigation">

    <a href="#" class="hamburger">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>

    <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>


    <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried your example and it works, but then I copied the Javascript code into my full one and it still doesn't do anything which makes me think there's an issue elsewhere in my code, do you think that's possible?

Comment: Almost certainly. Feel free to post a link to the full example and I'll try trace the issue.

Comment: Much appreciated! Here is a link to a repository with what I have going on https://github.com/Henchen99/responsive_website_dropdown

Comment: Works fine in codepen: https://codepen.io/j0r_dan/pen/PoBYaeq

Comment: Thats bizarre! It doesn't seem to work when opening it directly on chrome (at least for me)

Comment: The codepen isn't working for you? I've just tried Chrome, and it works no issue

Comment: Codepen is working, but for me, if I open the index.html file from my folder and it opens in chrome, it doesn't work. very strange

Comment: Ahh, the issue (locally at least) will be because you're loading the script before the body so when you `addEventListener` the elements you're binding to, won't exist yet. Move `<script src="script.js"></script>` below the `</body>` tag. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: That works now! Thank you so much for your help and patience, literally saved me hours!